# Can I award a second bounty to an answer that I have previously awarded a bounty?

Tags: support

If I have offered a bounty and awarded it to an answer, can I subsequently offer a second bounty and award it to the answer that I awarded my first bounty to?

My rationale is to increase the net reputation gain of the user who has an even more worthy answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But a subsequent bounty set on the same question by the same person has a higher minimum possible bounty amount.